# Classifying the stationary point of $f(x,y) = 4y^2 + 6yx^2 + 17$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, stationary-point

Given the function $f(x,y) = 4y^2 +6yx^2 + 17$, I found the single stationary point $(0,0)$.

I then tried to use the Hessian matrix to classify it as a local minimum/maximum/saddle point, but the determinant is zero. I'm not sure how else I can classify this point. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @user6725906 yes you're right, sorry! I accidentally typed the stationary point I found for a different problem  >.<

Comment: What you can do is to check whether the at (0,0) the function has a local minimum, maximum or neither. For this you can consider what happens when you move away from the origin in particular directions. For example, in the direction (0,1) we have $f(0,\varepsilon)=17+4\varepsilon^2>f(0,0) \quad \forall \varepsilon>0$.

Comment: One question related with this! When you actually get the determinant to be zero, what can you to determine wether it is a max/min or saddle point? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation the Hessian test is inconclusive so you can try to prove/disprove the existence of a local maxima/minima by definition.

For simplicity's sake I'll work instead with the function $f(x,y) = 4y^2 +6yx^2$ since the $17$ doesn't change the nature of the stationnary point.

With this new function we have $f(0,0) = 0$.

Notice that for $y \geq 0$ we have $f(x,y) \geq 0$. Indeed if $f(x,y)$ was negative then we would have
\begin{align*}4y^2+6yx^2 < 0 &\iff 4y^2 < -6yx^2 \\
& \iff y < -\frac{3}{2}x^2 < 0 
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction.

Therefore $f$ cant have a local maximum at $(0,0)$ since the function takes larger value whenever $y>0$.

To show that $(0,0)$ is a local minimum we must show that $f$ is positive on a small open neighbourhood around $0$. That is

$$ \exists \epsilon >0 : \vert (x,y)\vert < \epsilon \implies f(x,y) \geq 0. $$

We've already shown that $f$ is positive when $y$ is positive. If $y\leq  0$  then we have

\begin{align*}
4y^2+6yx^2 \geq 0 &\iff 4y^2 \geq -6yx^2 \\
&\iff  y \leq -\frac{3}{2}x^2
\end{align*}

Let $1 > \epsilon >0$ then consider

$$\tilde x  = \epsilon/2$$
$$\tilde y = \frac{1}{2} \frac{-3}{2}\tilde x^2  > \frac{-3}{4}\tilde x^2$$

By our choice for $\tilde x$ and $\tilde y$ we have $f(\tilde x,\tilde y) < 0$ but also $\tilde x^2 + \tilde y^2 < \epsilon^2$ which means that $f$ cant be a local minimum.

Since $(0,0)$ isn't a local maxima or local minima it is a saddle point.

Comment: Ohhh I see! Thanks a lot!